# OpenCV namedWindow() create a window then not responding and crash( QT 5.11 + OpenCV 4.5.3)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, crash

```
include .....
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    namedWindow("My Image");
    waitKey();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's code. A window displayed and then program crashed.

---

I followed the tutorial that used Qt+mingw to build mingw version lib.
If I use msvc version lib and compiler directly (don't need to build lib manually) , it works fine.
Now I believe that maybe some procedure lead the error. Just use msvc be OK.

Comment: remove `waitKey();`

Comment: Crash as usual.

Comment: Isn't this mixing the Qt GUI and the OpenCV GUI interface? What happens if you remove the `QApplication a(argc, argv);` and the `return a.exec();`?

Comment: @Yun, I delete QApplication a(argc, argv); and return set 0; same issue.

Comment: @SKIIiii How have you installed Qt and opencv? Also what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc, Yeah I've installed the OpenCV .Cmake the CV source and output lib and bin. Then include the header and lib in Qt .pro file. OS is win10 .  I want to load image to show in OpenCV window. Other api can work such as  cv::imread() .

Comment: @eyllanesc, I tried the Visual Code environment it works fine. I guess QT environment not  well. Maybe I should re-install OpenCV in Qt.